# Constructing a uniform convergence sequence

Tags: uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, smooth-functions

Let $f : \overline{\Omega} \subset \mathbb{R}^{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{2}(\overline{\Omega})$ function. Can we always construct a sequence $f_{n}$ such that $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly in $\overline{\Omega}$? In this case, $\Omega$ is a bounded open set. If I weaken the condition to $C(\overline{\Omega})$, can I also construct such a sequence as well?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that you can just let $f_n$ equal $f$, then the sequence of $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much... However, I want to know non-constant sequence with respect to $n$.

Comment: The image of $\Omega$ under $f$ is a bounded set  because $\Omega$ is compact. So for a non-constant sequence let $f_n=(1+1/n)f$ if $f\ne 0, $ or $f_n=1/n$ if $f$ is constantly $0$.